# Negative boolean options --no-whatever in optparse?

Tags: python, optparse

With `optparse`, is there a simple way to define negative options, e.g., `--no-cleanup`?

I did it this way, but it's cumbersome and bug-prone, especially due to the `None` check which is easy to forget and leave out:

```
#!/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import optparse

def main(argv):
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage: %prog [options]")
    parser.add_option("--no-cleanup",
                      dest = "cleanup",
                      action = "store_false",
                      help = "do cleanup at end?")

    (opts, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if opts.cleanup == None:
        opts.cleanup = True

    # do stuff ...

    if opts.cleanup:
        print("Cleaning up!", file = sys.stderr)
    else:
        print("Not cleaning up", file = sys.stderr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like `Getoptions::Long` in Perl, where I can define an option `cleanup` as boolean and then it will automatically provide `--cleanup` and `--no-cleanup` and set my boolean variable accordingly.

Comment: argparse has this functionality - or is that not an option?

Comment: @jterrace: I use Python v2.6, so I think I don't have argparse.

Comment: @Frank, argparse runs on python2.6, it's just not in the standard library.  If you have setuptools, `easy_install argparse` has always worked just fine for me.

Comment: @jterrace, I'm not completely sure that argparse has more functionality than optparse in this situation (although I would still highly recommend it above optparse).

Comment: And one other comment...generally it is better practice to use the `is` operator when testing for `None` since `None` is a singleton.  (That way user defined classes which override `__eq__` are guaranteed to not evaluate to `True`) -- in other words `myclassinstance == None` could potentially be `True` whereas `myclassinstance is None` will never be.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I installed argparse using `pip-python` now.

Answer (score 4):

If I was to do this using optparse (or argparse for that matter -- assuming you want to add a --cleanup and --no-cleanup flag in one command), I would just subclass the option parser class...  Something like:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
class MyOptParse(OptionParser):
      def boolean(self,dest,**kwargs):
          self.add_option('--%s'%dest,dest=dest,action='store_true',**kwargs)
          self.add_option('--no-%s'%dest,dest=dest,action='store_false',**kwargs)
```

Of course, this is a complete hack, but I think it's pretty obvious where I'm going with it...You can make boolean behave however you want it to (reformatting help, accepting a default value so that either '--blah' or '--no-blah' is set as the default, etc...)

I think that

```
parser=MyOptParse()
parser.boolean('cleanup',default=True,help="Do/Do Not do cleanup")
```

should work and get rid of the `if options.cleanup is None` line while it's at it since the default is set, although the help message will be repeated (with the code I provided)

If you just want to add defaults for a particular flag (to get rid of the check for `None`), you can use the default keyword to add_option, OR, according to the optparse documentation ...

> A clearer way to specify default values is the **set_defaults()** method of OptionParser, which you can call at any time before calling **parse_args()**:  e.g. `parser.set_defaults(verbose=True)`

Comment: you should add a `.replace('-', '_')` in `dest` argument. Is is possibile to condense the help, to avoid redundances, as in `man gcc`?